# BOOTSTRAP 4 - Join Scrollspy to Scrolltop

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, bootstrap-4

I'm getting closer to HTML, CSS ,JAVA in BOOTSTRAP.
I'm trying to "merge" the SCROLLSPY function to SCROLLTOP. I would like to change appearance (size, color ...) All responsive.

For SCROLLTOP I use this script but it is not responsive:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(window).on("scroll", function() {
    if ($(window).scrollTop() >= 50) {
      $(".navbar").addClass("compressed");
    
    } else {
      $(".navbar").removeClass("compressed");
    
    }

    if ($(window).scrollTop() >= 1000) {
      $(".navbar").addClass("compressed2");

    } else {
      $(".navbar").removeClass("compressed2");

    }
  });
});
```

For SCOLLSPY I use this:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('body').scrollspy({target: ".navbar", offset: 50});

  $("#navbarTarget a").on('click', function(event) {
    if (this.hash !== "") {
      event.preventDefault();

      var hash = this.hash;

      
      $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $(hash).offset().top
      }, 800, function(){

        window.location.hash = hash;
      });
    }  
  });
});
```

There is a way to use ID or HREF ... or other functions (which I do not know) to start an animation.

THX

Comment: can you explain in clear how you want to use scrollspy or scrollytop, i use this function in my website `https://nisharg.me` , follow this, **i don't do any promotion of my website**

Comment: Hello.
I want my navigation bar to change color while I scroll the page. For example:

home = red navbar

conatatti = orange navbar

about = yellow navbar

With the SCROLLTOP function I can create the effect I want, but it is not responsive.

I was thinking of using SCROLLSPY (I already use it for the navbar links)

So, instead of saying SCROLLTOP to change color after scrolled 500px ... and rechange color after scrolled to 1000px ... etc ...
The idea is to tell SCROLLTOP to change color using ID of the navbar (with SCROLLSPY i use #navbarTarget):